# Sql syntax error on DROP TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a MySQL table with the following code:

```
CREATE DATABASE 
  IF NOT EXISTS myusers;USE 
    DROP TABLE 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myusers`.`users`;CREATE TABLE `myusers`.`users` 
                 ( 
                              `username`  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
                              `password`  VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
                              `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
                              `lastname`  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
                              `phone`     INT NULL, 
                              PRIMARY KEY (`username`) 
                 )
```

However, I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE
>       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myusers`.`users`' at line 2

I have limited knowledge of MySQL. From what I know about SQL syntax this looks fine.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: Seems like you have "DROP TABLE" twice.  I don't know the mysql syntax, but this seems likely to be incorrect.

Comment: i also see USE with a blank.  seems odd

Comment: Where to begin?  `CREATE DATABASE <name needed here>`.  Then you have `IF NOT EXISTS myusers;USE ` which seems to make no sense.  etc, etc.  The only advice I can give is to read the manual and actually look up the syntax for each individual command you're trying to write....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `USE` should be followed by a database name.
- There is extra `DROP Table`.
- Drop the table if exists `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users` first.
- Then create the table.

Like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myusers; 
USE myusers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `myusers`.`users` 
    ( 
    `username`  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `password`  VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
    `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `lastname`  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `phone`     INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`username`) 
);
```

Comment: @MatBailie The first line is to create the database if not exists, I fixed it. But, still does makes little sense.